# JAVA :How to determine the index of the next character in a string NOT equal to a set of delimiters

Tags: java, string, count, delimiter, cpu-word

I don't think this question is very complicated to an experienced programmer, but I'm pretty new to it so I'm struggling.
I have a list of delimiters declared before a java class as such:

```
public static final String DELIMITERS = ",<.>/?;:'\"[{]}\\|=+-_)(*&^%$#@!`~ \t\n";
```

I'd like to create a method that takes two parameters (a starting index and a string). The goal is to read through the string and return the next index that corresponds to a character NOT in the list of delimiters given above. If the starting index is a negative number or greater than the length of the text, the method should simply return -1. Otherwise it just returns the index of the next character NOT in the delimiter list.
This is what I have so far:

```
public static boolean isDelimiter(char c) {
    String letter = "" + c;
    if(DELIMITERS.contains(letter)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public static int posNextWord(int startPosition, String text) {
    boolean isWord = false;
    int nextWordPosition = 0;
    if(startPosition < 0 || startPosition > (text.length()-1)){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        while(isWord = false) {
            for (int i = startPosition; i < text.length(); i++) {
                if(!isDelimiter(text.charAt(i))){
                    nextWordPosition = nextWordPosition + i + startPosition;
                    isWord = true;
                }
                else{
                    isWord = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return nextWordPosition;
    }

}
```

}

When I run this program with a sample text and index, however, the method just returns the number 0. Any help at all would be much appreciated. Also, the method isDelimiter is required for use in the posNextWord() method.

Comment: Show the main method where you call `posNextWord`

Comment: I think you need to `break` after `isWord = true;`

Comment: I can't really ; it's part of a larger assignment. This method is simply to be used with a similiar method (posNextDelimiter()) in order to create a third method to determine the word count of a set of lines input by the user

Comment: Watch out for `while (isWord = false)`; that should have been `==`, but in this case you didn't need the `while` loop at all. `while (!isWord)` would have been better, if the `while` loop had actually been needed.

Answer (score 2):

This entire block of code is the problem:

```
while(isWord = false) {
    for (int i = startPosition; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if(!isDelimiter(text.charAt(i))){
            nextWordPosition = nextWordPosition + i + startPosition;
            isWord = true;
        }
        else{
            isWord = false;
        }
    }
}
return nextWordPosition;
```

First of all, you only need one loop to check each character of your loop. You don't need a `while` and a `for`. Second, if you want to find the first non-matching `char`, you can just return when you find it.

Like this:

```
for (int i = startPosition; i < text.length(); i++) {
    if(!isDelimiter(text.charAt(i))){
        return i + startPosition;
    }
}
return -1;
```

Comment: @JBarron No problem, happy to help! If this solved the problem please remember to upvote and accept =]

Answer (score 1):

See documented comments. Don't hesitate to ask if it is not clear :

```
public static boolean isDelimiter(char c) {

    String letter = "" + c;
    if(DELIMITERS.contains(letter)){
        return true;
    }
    //else{ this else is not needed
        System.out.println(letter +" is not a delimiter");
        return false;
    //}
}

public static int posNextWord(int startPosition, String text) {

    //boolean isWord = false; not used 
    int nextWordPosition = 0;
    if((startPosition < 0) || (startPosition > (text.length()-1))){
        return -1;
    }
    //else{   this is not needed
    //while(isWord = false) {

        for (int i = startPosition; i < text.length(); i++) {

            if(!isDelimiter(text.charAt(i))){
                nextWordPosition = nextWordPosition + i + startPosition;
                //isWord = true;
                return nextWordPosition; //as Scary Wombat commented 
            }
            //else{
            //  isWord = false;
            //}

         }
        //isWord = false;
    //}
    return nextWordPosition;
    // }

}
```

BTW: I don't think it is a good idea to return 0 as "not found" result. 0 may be  returned also as valid "found" position.